# Having issue with PUT Redis cache method in Laravel

Tags: laravel, redis

```
    public function latest($count)
        {
            $key = 'latest.' . $count;
            $cacheKey = $this->getCacheKey($key);

            $articles_latest = Redis::get($cacheKey);
            if($articles_latest)
                return $articles_latest;
            $articles_latest = Articles::orderBy('id', 'desc)->take($count)->get();           
            Redis::put($cacheKey, $articles_latest, 1);
            return $articles_latest;
        }
```

.env:

```
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
```

Execution of code above gives error:
Predis\ClientException: Command 'PUT' is not a registered Redis command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the configured redis cache through the [Cache facade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/cache), also you can use the remember function for this:

```
    public function latest($count)
        {
            $key = 'latest.' . $count;
            $cacheKey = $this->getCacheKey($key);

            return Cache::remember($cacheKey, 60, function() {
                return Articles::orderBy('id', 'desc)->take($count)->get();
            });
        }
```

I'm assuming the 1 was for one minute, please note that with Laravel 5.8 the cache parameter list was changed to use seconds instead of minutes. Also you should check out the [PSR](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) coding standards about code formatting.